# Login/logout issue for multiple IIS same applications under the same site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin-middleware

I have deployed same application as two sites[Production and Development] in IIS 8.0 with two port number. The problem is the follow:

Open the browser and login the first application[Production];
Open another browser tab and login the second application[Development];
The first application automatically logout.

Any idea of having both should be logged in and use?

My file Startup.Auth.cs:

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

  // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
  // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
  // Configure the sign in cookie
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    CookieName="my-very-own-cookie-name",
    //ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
      // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
      // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
      OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
          validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromHours(applTime),
          regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
      OnResponseSignIn = context =>
      {
          context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
          context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(idleTime);
      }

    }
  });
  app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Comment: Cookies are set per domain, and your IIS sites likely have the same domain (just different ports).

Comment: What @HereticMonkey said.  Trying two completely different browsers (FF and IE for instance) rather than a tab in the same browser should work just fine.  If you must use the same browser, open one of them in an InPrivate window - this should still keep the cookies separated.

Comment: Yeah it is in the same domain[same IP]. I tried with IE and CHROME browser with tabs as well as separate window. Both has showing same Cookies as you mentioned. My query: Can we open two tabs with two same instances of PORT difference and use it.

Comment: As long as the domains/ips are the same, they'll share the same cookie. You might find other authentication schemes more amenable to your situation (find ones that use "origin" (which uses scheme [http|https], domain, and port) rather than "host".

Comment: Can you suggest me the authentication schemes with OWIN which supports both http/https?

Comment: @Tommy&Heretic Monkey:Is there any way to configure cookies, so that both sites[Production/Testing] can be used in tabs?